# MS Excel : How to get the changed date format when exporting as csv?

Tags: mysql, excel, date

I have a MS Excel file in which a column contains date in the format m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy. I wanted all these dates to be imported in to a MySQL table.

So in MS Excel, I changed the cell format to custom date 'yyyy-mm-dd' and everything looked fine in the excel columns. When I exported it as .csv, all dates were in the original format i.e., m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy but not as 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Please help me in this regard. Thank you!

Comment: changing the cell's *format* does not do anything to change the date's *value* which is the source of your problem. Consider changing the dates to STRING data type and this should preserve the data in the "format" you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David mentioned, you may have to replace the text before importing it to the MySQL table. You can try this formula:

`=TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")`

And copy down. Then do a copy->Paste Values into the original date column. Then delete the temporary column with the `Text()` formula.

Try importing it after you replace the text. It should work out.

Comment: David & Joseph, thanks for your explanation. I followed your suggestion and exported as .txt instead of .csv; this did the trick for me :)